# Executing PHP code only once, when the node is created

Tags: nodes, tokens

I am using Drupal 7 with  the Token module.
I wrote PHP code using the token field that can satisfy loading a specific node, updating some field values, and saving the node (using node functions).

When editing this node the code run again; I just want to run this code when creating this node. How can I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [`hook_node_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) in a custom module to run your code when the node is created.

```
function hook_node_insert($node) {
  // To include @marcvangend's comment.
  if ($node->type == 'type') {
    // Run code here only for node of type 'type'.
  }
  // Run code here for all nodes...
}
```

Comment: thanks but in this way how can i run this code for specific content type?

Comment: Add an if-statement and check for `$node->type`.